# Is it possible to declare a response address for Google Maps Javascript API request?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When I said that the response of the Google Maps Javascript API could be manipulated by the client, talking with a Google Maps employee, he told me that the request could be made by the client and the answer be directly sent to my server.
Unfortunately I just can not find a possibility to declare a response address.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Dr.Molle E.g. use the Distance Matrix Service to calculate shipping costs without the danger of exceeding usage quota. So the request has to come from the client. But if the client receives the response and alters it (on purpose) the calculated shipping costs might be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there is no implemented way to do this(maybe there is an option with a business licence).

What you can do:
Setup a serverside script that will be called immediately(via ajax) when the response arrives and pass the response to that script. You may store now the orginal response on the server and don't have to trust anymore on data that come from the client.(but of course this also may be intercepted by experienced users if they want to)